# jQuery not firing recaptcha's callback function

Tags: jquery, recaptcha

I've read other posts, But I couldn't figure this out.
**My html:**

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="XXXXX" data-callback="recaptchaCallback"></div>
```

**My Script:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var captchaCalled = false;

  function recaptchaCallback() {
    captchaCalled = true;
    alert("Called");
  }

  $("#contact_form").submit(function (e) {
    if (name === '' || email === '' || user_message === '' || captchaCalled === false) {
      $("#message_p1").css("display" , "block");
      $("#message_p1").text("All field are necessary");
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

I tried moving the call back function out of **$(document).ready(function....**  it was called but not submitting form.

Comment: Your `recaptchaCallback` isn't set on global scope. Don't wrap it inside document ready because anyway it doesn't make much sense here. And let your binding of submit event inside the ready handler

Comment: You just declared it, not fired it.

Comment: @A.Wolff How Can I call it? Because I'm using a variable called **captchaCalled** in the document ready.

Comment: @Messi.Meysam You just need to wrap `$("#contact_form").submit(...)` inside ready handler, all the rest shouldn't